# Import MySQLdump to PostgreSQL schema

Tags: postgresql

I have a web application that uses MySQL for its database. Due to a change in course in that project, I am wanting to move away from MySQL and use PostgreSQL with schemas. Specifically, I'm building a multi-tenancy web application where each tenant gets their own schema in the database using the PostgreSQL package [Django Tenant Schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The project has been in use for about a year using MySQL, but with only a single user. That means all records in the MySQL database can be put into one schema in the PostgreSQL database.

I'm wondering what would be involved in moving all of the user's data from the MySQL into a single schema on the PostgreSQL database.

I have found [this tool](https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter) for converting a MySQL dump to a PostgreSQL friendly format, but it doesn't speak to how I can then import that dump into a specific schema.

Do you have any thoughts on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at pgloader (http://pgloader.io/howto/pgloader.1.html). Here is a basic example of how it works:

```
createdb pagila  
pgloader mysql://user@localhost/sakila postgresql:///pagila
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your converted MySQL dump like this:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL search_path = desired_schema;
<dump goes here>
COMMIT;
```

Then

1. all objects created without an explicit schema qualifier will be created in `desired_schema`.
2. everything will be done inside a single transaction, so if some statement fails, everything will be undone.